# submitting form and variables together through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

I'm using 2 types of submit.

There is $.post

```
$.post('servers_side.php', { var1: var1, var2:var2},
function(result) 
{
some code...
});
```

which sends separate variables to server side script.

And there is AjaxSubmit plugin which submits the whole form

```
$('#form').ajaxSubmit({success: function(result)
{
some code...
}
});
```

But now I have the following task let's say I have a form and a few variables which I must submit at the same time.

So Is that possible to submit form + some variables together ?

Comment: I don't know enough `ajaxSubmit` but wouldn't [`.serlialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

And here is how you can submit:

```
var Vars = {var1: var1, var2:var2};
var varsData = $.param(Vars);

// form data
var formData = $('#formID').serialize();

var data = varsData + '&' + formData;

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'servers_side.php',
  data: data,
  success: function(res){ alert (res) }
})
```

---

You can use [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to convert an array or an object into url-friendly name-value paris. You may also need to use [`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to convert form data into name-value paris. Here is how you can go about:

```
var Vars = {var1: var1, var2:var2};
var varsData = $.param(Vars);

// form data
var formData = $('#formID').serialize();

var data = varsData + '&' + formData;
```

Now `data` contains all data of your custom vars and form elements you can send in ajax request.

Comment: I've ran into problem. How can I submit them now ? using $.post ? can u write sample line? how can I put this data into $.post ?

Comment: and how must I decode them on server side ? treat them like array or what ? cause if I sent data then I must $_POST(data) object there, but then how can I access my variables ? in php ?

Comment: @David: See the updated answer please. To get them on server side, you need to use POST array followed by name of var or form element eg `$_POST['name here']`

Comment: $.post cannot understand only data. It needs data:something, otherwise javascript stops. Am I doing something wrong or $.post cannot do what we want ?

Comment: DONE! u had "}" which must be deleted

Comment: @David: You can also use `$.ajax` if you are having problems with `$.post`, see updated answer please.

Comment: no thanks I'll stick to $.post much easier to write. As for the rest GREAT THANKS! :)

Comment: Have new problems, Seems to me this method cannot send files if file-inputs are in the form. What can I do with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible but code might look messy. As **best practice** you should add some `hidden` fields

```
<form>
   .
   .
   .
   <input type="hidden" name="var1" id="var1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="var2" id="var2" />
   <input type="hidden" name="var3" id="var3" />
   .
   .
   .
</form>
```

And use this JavaScript to set values to these `hidden` fields

```
$("#var1").val("some data 1");
$("#var2").val("some data 2");
$("#var3").val("some data 3");
```

And you can carry on with your existing `$.post()` code